# RIGHT TO LEFT when creating PDF in android

Tags: android, pdf, itext, hebrew

I'm trying to generate PDF file that contains Hebrew words.

When file is created all the Hebrew letters are deleted and only the English one are

in the file.

Can any one help me with this problem?

I'm using iText 5.4.3

This is my code when i add a new paragraph

```
    Paragraph p0 = new Paragraph("טופס קריאת שירות");
    BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H , BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font fontHebrew = new Font(unicode, 12, Font.NORMAL);
    p0.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
    p0.setFont(fontHebrew);

    //add paragraph to document    
    doc.add(p0);
```

Thank's.

Comment: Please refrain from saying *I'm using com.itextpdf.com.lowagie* as that doesn't tell anyone which version you're using (in general) and to me it feels as you're using my name (in particular). Say "I'm using the obsolete iText version 2.1.7" or something like that. That's more to the point.

Comment: You're right. I added the version i'm using.

Comment: There's no such thing as 5.4.3 com.lowagie. Also, if you say version 5.4.3, are you talking about the JAVA iText or about the Android port iTextG? See http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextg/ It's confusing.

Comment: Also: what have you tried. By default, iText uses the Standard Type1 font `Helvetica` and as you know, that font doesn't support Hebrew, hence no Hebrew characters will be shown. Surely you're using a font such as `MS Arial Unicode`?

Comment: Hi Bruno, First of thank you. I added the code i'm using to add a new paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you added is wrong on many levels.

1. You're adding Hebrew characters in source code. These characters can get lost if the file is saved using the wrong encoding, if the file is compiled using the wrong encoding, etc... Use the Unicode notation instead of actual characters.
2. Maybe not wrong, but to be checked: you're using arial.ttf, shouldn't you be using arialuni.ttf? Also: make sure you pack the ttf in your APK (you wouldn't be the first to forget to ship a resource).
3. I can't read Hebrew, but I know it's written from right to left. RTL isn't supported in the `Paragraph` class, only in `PdfPCell` and `ColumnText`.

See [the examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=410) to find out how it's done: [say_peace.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/say_peace.pdf) is done using a table; [ligatures_2.pd](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/ligatures_2.pdf)f is done using a column (the second example is in Arabic, but it's the same principle as Hebrew).